# App Store - Horizontal wheel app picker

Tags: ios

can you please give me a direction how to achieve similar app picker like we can see on top of App Store (check out a screenshot)? I assume we are talking about collection view with one row and customized cell's size etc. but I couldn't find any sample/tutorial/external library.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick Lockwood's [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Looks great. Carousel is probably the keyword I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the keyword is "cover flow".